# Replace parts of string on line using XSLT 2

Tags: java, xml, xslt, soap

I have a WSDL, in which  I would like to override the soap address location using XSLT 2.0.

For example:
`&lt;soap:address location="https://xyz.company.com/portal/services/Service?param1=myapp&amp;webService=TestWebService"/&gt;`

For the location attribute, I would like

`xyz.company.com` to become `abc.company.com`

`myapp` to become `xyzapp`.

I have written the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="vLocation" select="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service/wsdl:port/soap:address/@location"/>
    <xsl:template match="@location">

      <xsl:attribute name="location">
          <xsl:value-of select="replace($vLocation, xyz.company.com', 'abc.company.com')"/> 
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works for replacing point 1 -> `xyz.company.com` to become `abc.company.com`.

But how can I also replace point 2. ->`myapp` to become `xyzapp`

Please advise.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `replace` again as in

```
<xsl:template match="soap:address/@location">
  <xsl:attribute name="location" select="replace(replace(., 'xyz\.company\.com', 'abc.company.com'), 'myapp', 'xyzapp')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I tried the multi replace before but it did not work.